# Swift RSS Feed mark as read

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi i am making a RSS Reader and i wanted to know if anyone could help me add a "Read/Unread" system for the feeds, so like they have the blue dots for them and when you open it the blue dot goes away like the mail app. I have no idea where to start with this if anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: Just have an Array variable in your class, and when the article is clicked on in the table view, add the article's url to the array. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can use `contains(myArray, articleURL)` to determine if it is read or not.

Comment: @erdekhayser But that will only save it untill you exit the app won't it?

Comment: That array can be stored to NSUserDefaults using `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey: @"ReadArticle")`

Comment: So this array will grow infinitely with time?